# Head to another Schengen country with type D visa of Denmark

Tags: schengen-visas, denmark

I have a residence permit of Denmark but have lost my residence permit card here in USA and got a re-entry permit visa (Type D) valid for Denmark from Danish embassy. 
The question: Can I fly to Norway with this re-entry permit (Type D)? 
Note: This is not duplicated question. 
1) I am not saying transit via Norway. I know transit is possible.  2) I do not mean entering to Schengen via Norway and heading to Denmark, I know this is allowed. 
3) I know with type D visa I can travel within Schenegen.

My question is different as for the officer in the airport[image] I just have a flight ticket to Norway. I will stay there for few weeks before heading to Denmark. Is this allowed?
Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps you should post your update as an answer and accept it, but please note my [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133586/head-to-another-schengen-country-with-type-d-visa-of-denmark/133587?noredirect=1#comment331975_133587).  It is not at all clear to me why the Norwegian border police told you that.  There's nothing on your visa that suggests it shouldn't function as a normal D visa allowing you to visit other Schengen countries.

Comment: Really have no idea what to do, if my travelling to Norway with this type of visa is not against the rules, then why I should be denied. The problem is that we are a family of 3 and if we can not fly to Norway, this means cancellations of 3 tickets (no refunds), buying 3 new tickets to Denmark+ buying another 3 tickets from Denmark to Norway.

Comment: hello, did this work out for you? do you have any follow ups please? I got a digital nomad visa for estonia I'm confused as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is allowed unless your stay in Norway will exceed the 90/180 limit that applies in Schengen countries other than Denmark.  A type D visa authorizes the holder to travel to other Schengen countries for up to 90 days in any 180-day period.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the kind of emergency document the OP describes. Are you sure it can be used just like a regular D document?

Comment: Not that it matters for the 'few weeks', which OP is asking about, but if you go into details, I am pretty sure that the Nordic countries have more lenient agreements regarding mutual recognition of residence permits, which pre-date the Schengen agreement. I don't think the Schengen 90/180 rule applies here.

Comment: @o.m. The logical procedure for someone who has lost a residence permit outside the Schengen area is to issue a D visa, which could reasonably be described as an emergency visa.  But under the Schengen codes, a D visa is a D visa.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I got a bit worried after reading some stories of people travelling from China with type D visa valid for country X while they were flaying to country Y in Schengen area.

Comment: But his type D visa only says DANMARK and not SCHENGEN-STATERNE. It really makes no difference?

Comment: I guess this makes a difference.

Comment: @MichaelHampton all D visas these days only list the country of issue in the "valid for" field.  That's because it's valid *as a long stay visa* only in that country.

Answer (score 0):

I called Norwegian police border and they confirmed that I can NOT fly to Norway if it is not a transit to Denmark. They also said you may get a problem in departure point! I contacted embassy of Norway here in USA and they could not answer the question saying that my question is very specific question!